GroupBy Window Aggregation: Handling empty windows
While consuming from a streaming source,

we use a Groupby Window Aggregation: .group_by(col('name'))) (cf. here)
and have a table with all possible name values (in the below example ['Alice', 'Bob'])

After windowing+group_by, the aggregated data stream has one row for every window/name combination with an event. How can I fill the stream to return every key in every time-window filling up the missing datapoints wit, say 0?
Find a minimal working example below which I want to modify such that I get a row for Alice and Bob in every window 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s.
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.set_parallelism(1)
    t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env)

    # define the source with watermark definition
    ds = env.from_collection(
        collection=[
            (Instant.of_epoch_milli(1000), 'Alice', 110.1),
            (Instant.of_epoch_milli(2000), 'Bob', 53.1),
            (Instant.of_epoch_milli(3000), 'Bob', 3.1),
            (Instant.of_epoch_milli(4000), 'Bob', 30.2),
        ],
        type_info=Types.ROW([Types.INSTANT(), Types.STRING(), Types.FLOAT()]))

    table = t_env.from_data_stream(
        ds,
        Schema.new_builder()
              .column_by_expression("ts", "CAST(f0 AS TIMESTAMP(3))")
              .column("f1", DataTypes.STRING())
              .column("f2", DataTypes.FLOAT())
              .watermark("ts", "ts")
              .build()
    ).alias("ts", "name", "price")

    # define the tumble window operation
    table = (
        table
        .window(Tumble.over(lit(1).seconds).on(col("ts")).alias("w"))
        .group_by(col('name'), col('w'))
        .select(
            col('name'),
            col("w").start.alias('window'),
            col('price').sum.alias('result'),
        )
    )

    # submit for execution
    table.execute().print()


The standard approach to this issue of "empty windows" is to have a custom source that emits a fake event with an appropriate time for each window, for each unique key. Then you union that stream with your real stream, before doing your .group_by(). Since you have a table with all of the unique key values, you could use this in your source.
There's this solution for such a source, though it's Scala code.

I am not sure if it is easily possible to build a RichParallelSourceFunction in Python? Moreover, is it possible to build such a custom source based on the Watermarks?

You should be able to create at least a SourceFunction in Python (I found some examples online).

Not sure what you mean by "...based on the Watermarks"? Watermarks are generated by extracting timestamps from records being returned by a source, so as long as the timestamp in the record is appropriate (one per windowing period) then it should work if you're correctly generating watermarks.
